# What kind of relationship does an interface have with it implementing class?

Tags: java

A subclass has a relationship that is described as `IS-A` with it base class, but a base class does not share this kind of relationship with it subclass. I was wandering what kind of relationship an interface have with it implementing class since an object of that class can be passed to interface object and the interface object can only access methods defined it concrete Interface.

```
public class main {
    public static void main(String[]args){

        Nigeria ng = new Nigeria(){};

        //Interface object can accept Nigerias object which is not posible in Inheritance
        Continent continent = ng; 

        //prints Country is in Africa
        continent.Africa(); 

        //continent.language(); will not compile language is not in the interface

        //Print Democratic thought this should print Undefined since it is inialied with default.
        continent.Goverment(); 

    }

}
interface Continent{
    public void Africa();
    default void Goverment(){
        System.out.println("Undefined");
    }
}
class Nigeria implements Continent{
    @Override
    public void Africa(){
        System.out.println("Country is in Africa");
    }   
    public void language(){
        System.out.println("Official Language is English");
    }
    public void Goverment(){
        System.out.println("Democratic");
    }
}
```

Comment: It's the same as parent - child. The concrete class has an "is-a" relationship with its interface. It **is** a subtype of the interface type.

Comment: None. Interfaces don't know about the classes which implement them, just as base classes don't know anything about their derived classes.

Comment: @Filkolev  if Interface does not know about it implementing class, how does it know which methods are overridden and those that are not

Comment: @Nexima360 This is decided at RunTime by the JVM. Read about virtual methods.

Comment: @Nexima360, the interface doesn't know and doesn't care, it just provides a contract. It basically says "Anyone who claims to be e.g. `Comparable` must be able to compare himself to another with a `compareTo()` method". Besides, if a class implements an interface, it absolutely must implement ALL the methods in it (optionally, the class and some of the  methods may be abstract, leaving the actual implementation to concrete classes).

Answer (score 16):

If you are looking for English-language analogues, an Interface is not an "Is a..." nor "Has a..." relationship, but more an "Is...".

An Interface is not about the class that uses it.
It's about the consumer that asks for it.

If you wanted to see it as anything, you could see it as an adjective.

"He is Responsible".

Well, what does he do?

He finishes tasks; he takes ownership of his mistakes; he makes them right.

Is he a pilot, is he a surgeon, is he a doctor?
Is he a child, a father, a greatGrandfather?

Do you care?

I need a responsible person, to help me do this job.
Does ResponsiblePerson inherit from PoliceOfficer? Does Lawyer inherit from ResponsiblePerson, because I'm sure there can be irresponsible lawyers.

```
class Lawyer extends Person { }
class ResponsibleLawyer extends Lawyer implements ResponsibleEntity { }


class NeedyPerson extends Person {
  public void acceptHelp (ResponsibleEntity somebody) {
    try {
      somebody.attemptTask( someTask );
    } catch (TaskCompletionError err) {
      somebody.takeOwnership(err);
      somebody.fixMistake(err);
    }
  }
}
```

Can corporations be Responsible too?
Perhaps we don't see it too often, but it's theoretically possible:

```
class LawFirm extends CorporateEntity { }
class BetterLawFirm extends LawFirm implements ResponsibleEntity { }
```

Can `somebody` be a responsible corporate body? Well, so long as that corporate body does all of the same things that the responsible person would otherwise do, sure.

In another example, you might have a `Switchable` interface.
Looking at that name, you could surmise that the thing you're being given has a switch which can be poked.
So what methods might it have?

`on( )`
`off( )`
`toggle( )`
`isOn( )`

sounds like a useful set to have.

What benefit is there to having an interface like this?
Well, now I know that I can deal with a switch, and its lineage doesn't matter.

If all I want is a class which takes a switch and does something with it, why do I need to create dozens of classes, just to accept my dozens of things with switches?
Or override methods into the dirt to do the same.

```
class SwitchThrower {
  public void throwSwitch (CoffeeMaker coffeeMaker) { coffeeMaker.on(); }
  public void throwSwitch (LightSwitch lightSwitch) { lightSwitch.on(); }
  public void throwSwitch (GhostTrap ghostTrap) { ghostTrap.on(); }
  public void throwSwitch (TheHeat theHeat) { theHeat.on(); }
  public void throwSwitch (CarIgnition ignition) { ignition.on(); }
}
```

...

why not just:

```
class SwitchThrower {
  public void throwSwitch (Switchable switch) { switch.on(); }
}


class LightSwitch implements Switchable {
  private boolean currentlyOn;

  public LightSwitch (boolean initiallyOn) {
    currentlyOn = initiallyOn;
  }

  public LightSwitch () {
    currentlyOn = false;
  }

  public boolean on () {
    currentlyOn = true;
    return currentlyOn;
  }

  public boolean off () {
    currentlyOn = false;
    return currentlyOn;
  }

  public boolean toggle (boolean forceOn) {
    boolean state;
    if (forceOn == true) {
      state = on();
    } else {
      state = off();
    }
    return state;
  }

  public boolean toggle () {
    boolean state;
    if (isOn() == true) {
      state = off();
    } else {
      state = on();
    }
    return state;
  }

  public boolean isOn () {
    return currentlyOn;
  }
}
```

...et cetera

As you can see, aside from *describing a basic feature-set of the implementer*, interfaces are not about the class at all, but rather the *consumer*.

An even more awesome implementation of this, in different languages, is *_Traits_*.
Traits are typically like Interfaces, but they have default behaviour associated with them.

Looking at my `Switchable` and my `LightSwitch`, you could imagine that practically all classes with this switch would have the same methods, with the same method behaviour...

...so why would I rewrite all of those methods over again, if I'm already going through the trouble of defining the signature in the interface?
Why couldn't I just add default behaviour in there, and have it apply to the implementer, unless a method is overridden?

Well, that's what Traits / Mix-Ins allow.

Comment: Thank you for taking time to explain. Much appreciated.

Comment: Very useful and good explanation.

Answer (score 2):

The relationship is only the "contract" that the class is getting to implement the methods the interface is offering.

That is how java can separate **WHAT** objects can do (Interface) and **HOW** the inherited class will do it.